# BeautifulSoup cannot parse the website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to parse 'https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/treeView' with BeautifulSoup, but running the below code only gives me empty list `[]`

```
import json,requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url=('https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/treeView')
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all("ul", { "class" : "treeItem ng-scope" },recursive=False))
```

Can someone please help me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: If you look at the HTML source of the link you provide, there are no ul tags etc... basically, welcome to new fangled webpages.  I think something like Jasmine, or Selenium is probably your best bet.  On the other hand, if you look at what's being sent over the wire, you might be able to just fake out the API calls using requests and get parsed JSON data that's more useful anyways, but I didn't dig that deep

Comment: @Foon thanks for the comment, but when I open the page in Chrome developer mode, I can see the ul.

Comment: <ul class="treeItem ng-scope">
    <!-- ngRepeat: node in node.children -->
</ul> no content in ul

Comment: If you are trying to extract the text , you have to check it in <span ng-if="!node.strong" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Chemicals and Drugs [D]</span>

Comment: @ Foon, how can I fake out the API calls?

Comment: Seems this site uses Angular. The list is generated by javascript calls to the server. Like @Foon said, your best option is something like Selenium that drives a real browser.